# Solve a 2D linear recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations, wolfram-alpha

I need to know the solution of this recurrence:
$$2a[n,k-1]-a[n-1,k-1]-2a[n-1,k-2]+a[n-2,k-2]=a[n,k]$$

With the initial value unspecified.

Also, wolfram is good at solving linear 1D recurrence, but seems pretty lame on 2D version. Could you recommend me some 2D linear recurrence solver?

Could someone please help me? Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's not a single initial value, but rather all $a(n,k)$ where $n=0,1$ or $k=0,1$. It's easier to look at the generating function of this recurrence. It is a rational function in 2 variables, where the denominator only depends on this equation, but the numerator also depends on the initial conditions.

Comment: Thank you. But I don’t know why you mentioned numerator and denominator. I know rational function though.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_{n,k}=2a_{n,k-1}-a_{n-1,k-1}-2a_{n-1,k-2}+a_{n-2,k-2}\tag{1}$$

Let us have a graphical understanding of the dependencies, in particular in order to have a clear idea about the initializing data.

Here, the "computability" of red box $a_{n,k}$ relies recursively on the computability of the yellow boxes $a_{n,k-1}$, etc. arranged as a "Tetrix-like" shape, with a South-East general "sweeping" direction.

As a consequence, if you place the yellow shape at any place on the West and North borders, the process will be effective iff you have given initial values to **all green boxes (on two levels)** (as noted by @Alexander Burstein).

[image]

This infinite number of degrees of freedom prevents from giving a general solution.

Nevertheless, when I have simulated the creation of the table of the $a_{n,k}$ for many different initial values, a surprizingly common behavior is observable : the fact that, on the eastern border, one has always a same type of alternating values as can be seen on the example below (for $n=10$) :

[image]

where in this case, the significant values $a_{n,10}$ alternate in the following approximate way :

$$2.25, -7.06, 8.26,-4.73, 1.30, -0.16$$

What can be the explanation ?

Edit : you have suggested to take $n+k=m$ in (1), giving :

$$a_m=2a_{m-1}-a_{m-2}-2a_{m-3}+a_{m-4}$$

This linear recurrence has a characteristic polynomial

$$r^4-2r^3+r^2+2r-1=0$$

with solutions

$$r_1 \approx 0.46899, \ r_2 \approx -0.88320, \ r_3 \approx 1.55377e^{0.217i \pi}, \ r_4 \approx 1.55377e^{-0.217i \pi}$$

Therefore, the explicit solution of (2) has the following form :

$$a_m\approx \underbrace{a(0.46899)^m+b(-0.88320)^m}_{\text{tending to } 0}+(1.55377)^m(c  \cos(m 0.217 \pi)+d \sin(m 0.217 \pi)\tag{1}$$

(for certain constants $a,b,c,d$ relying on initial conditions, here assumed uniform, for example with all green borders set to $1$). explaining the long-term exponential trend in $(1.55377)^n$ coupled with a certain periodicity.

Comment: Any comment ?.... Could you say something about the origin of this problem ?

Comment: Sorry. I didn’t notice your answer. But I’m thinking if we set n+k=m, then we get 2a(m-1)-a(m-2)-2a(m-3)+a(m-4)=a(m). What if we solve this recurrence first?

Comment: I will answer you in some hours, when I will be back home.

Comment: I’ve been trying to solve the closed form of a(n)=abs(a(n-1)-a(n-2)), where a0 and a1 are real numbers. I noticed this recurrence is related to fractal, Fibonacci sequence, random matrices, continued fraction, etc. It’s possible that this problem could be solved using operators.

Comment: I now determine that the basis function of the closed form should be sign(x-c). If a0/a1 is a rational number, the sequence will end with “gcd(a0,a1), gcd(a0,a1), 0” periodically. And if f(x) is a0, f(h(x)) is a1, then f((h^n)(x)) is a(n), where h(x) = 1-abs(φ(1-x)-1). φ = (1+√5)/2. I came across to this 2D linear recurrence problem when I was solving the coefficients of f(x), in which the basis function is sgn(x-c).

Comment: I took a look on the problems you answered. Some of them are related to Fibonacci numbers. Not sure if you’re familiar with modular form. I hope you’d be interested in this a(n)=abs(a(n-1)-a(n-2)) recurrence I’m solving.   Oh, the domain of h(x) and f(x) is (0,1)

Comment: You could try b(n) = 1/abs(1-b(n-1)) first

Comment: 1) About the case $n+k=m$ see the edit I just added 2) About the new problem, why don't you transform it into a new "full flesh question" ?